# Jasmine AngularJS - How to Mock window.user.username

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am a Jasmine rookie and trying to figure out how to mock the window.user.username object when testing an angularjs using Jasmine.

var applicationUser = window.user.username;

Comment: in your prod code, inject $window instead of using window directly. Now mock $window.

Comment: Thanks @haimlit That helped ! I have posted the working code snippet below as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, Not Sure, if this is the right way. But it worked. Hope it helps.

```js
//Main Function
function MyController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.HeaderCtrl = function() {

      $scope.user = $window.user;
      ---

    }


    //Jasmine Code
    var $window;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$window_) {
      $window = _$window_;
      $window.user = 'xyz';
    }));

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('EpicController', {
        '$scope': $rootScope,
        '$window': $window
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it,

[Mocking window in an angularJS test](http://entwicklertagebuch.com/blog/2013/10/mocking-window-in-an-angularjs-test/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add user object to jasmine global space.

```js
//Main Function
function MyController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.HeaderCtrl = function() {

      $scope.user = $window.user;
      ---

    }


    //Jasmine Code
    var $window;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$window_) {
      jasmine.getGlobal().$window = _$window_;
       // OR
       // here i am assuming that user class has only username property
      jasmine.getGlobal().$windows = { "user": {"username": "xyz"}}; 
      $window.user = 'xyz';
    }));

    createController = function() {
      return $controller('EpicController', {
        '$scope': $rootScope,
        '$window': $window
      });
    };
```